# Laravel - get the data in a certain order…

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have a question about Laravel - Eloquent….

I have a table that has (amongst other things)

- id
- name (varchar)
- position (int)
- parent (int) -> id of the parent page (which results in 0 when it is part of the main menu)

My goal didn’t seem to me as difficult but I don’t get it right….
I need to do the following:

- Page in position 1

  - Child 1
  - Child 2
- Page in position 2
- Page in position 3

  - Child 1
- Page in position 4

Example Table:

```
+----+--------+------+  
| ID |Position|Parent|  
+----+--------+------+  
| 1  |   3    |  0   |
| 2  |   2    |  0   |
| 3  |   3    |  6   |
| 4  |   1    |  6   |
| 5  |   2    |  6   |
| 6  |   1    |  0   |
+----+--------+------+
```

Should result in:

6
 - 4
 - 5
 - 3
2
1

In fact, in my first foreach, I should be able to do this:

```
    if $page->children->count() > 0
```

I tried a lot of different things, in all ways possible but I don’t get to the result I want……
If someone has a solution for me, I will be happy and very grateful :D

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can read the table data in the controller and you can organize all the data in the view. In the view you can code two nested loops for the two levels you want to show.

Controller:

```
$items = $table->all();

return view('page', compact('items'));
```

View `page.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($items->where('parent', 0)->sortByDesc('id') as $menuFirstLevel)
    {{$menuFirstLevel->id}}
    @foreach($item->where('parent', $menuFirstLevel->id)->sortBy('foo-bar') as $menuSecondLevel)
        {{$menuSecondLevel->id}}
    @endif
@endif
```